# Oracle - View to fetch data gives different results in different environments

Tags: oracle, view

In Oracle (PROD), we will be creating views on table(s) and the users will be querying the views to fetch data for each reporting period (a single month, eg: between '01-DEC-2015' and '31-DEC-2015'). We created a view as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_TABLE1 AS SELECT ACCNT_NBR, BIZ_DATE, MAX(COL1) COL1, MAX(COL2) COL2 FROM TABLE1_D WHERE BIZ_DATE IN (SELECT BIZ_DATE FROM TABLE2_M GROUP BY BIZ_DATE) GROUP BY ACCNT_NBR, BIZ_DATE;
```

The issue here is TABLE1_D (daily table, has data from Dec2015 to Feb2016) has records with multiple dates for a month say for Dec2015, it has records with 01-DEC-2015, 02-DEC-2015,....,29-DEC-2015,30-DEC-2015 (may not be continuous, but loaded on business date) with each day having close to 2,500,000 of records.
TABLE2_M is a monthly table and has a single date for a month (eg for Dec2015 say 30-DEC-2015) with around 4000 records for each date.

When we query the view as

```
SELECT * FROM VW_TABLE1 WHERE BIZ_DATE BETWEEN '01-DEC-2015' AND '31-DEC-2015'
```

it returns the aggregated data in table TABLE1_D for 30-DEC-2015 as expected.  I thought the Grouping on BIZ_DATE in TABLE1_D is unnecessary as only one BIZ_DATE will be the output from the INNER query.
Checked by removing the BIZ_DATE in the final GROUP BY  assuming that there will be data for a single day from the inner query.
Hence took 2 rows for the dates 30-dec-2015 and 30-jan-2016 from both tables and created them in SIT for testing and created view as

```
CREATE VIEW VW_TABLE1 AS SELECT ACCNT_NBR, MAX(BIZ_DATE) BIZ_DATE, MAX(COL1) COL1, MAX(COL2) COL2 FROM TABLE1_D WHERE BIZ_DATE IN (SELECT BIZ_DATE FROM TABLE2_M GROUP BY BIZ_DATE) GROUP BY ACCNT_NBR;
```

The select with between for each month (or = exact month date) gives correct data in SIT; i.e., when used BETWEEN for a single month, it produces the respective months data.

```
SELECT * FROM VW_TABLE1 WHERE BIZ_DATE BETWEEN '01-DEC-2015' AND '31-DEC-2015';
    SELECT * FROM VW_TABLE1 WHERE BIZ_DATE = '30-DEC-2015';
```

With this, I modified the view DDL in PROD (to be same as SIT).  But surprisingly the same select (2nd one with ='30-DEC-2015' ; 1st one was taking too long due to volume of data, hence aborted)
returned no data; as I hope that the inner query is sending out dates all 30-DEC-2015 to 30-JAN-2016 and thereby the MAX(BIZ_DATE) is being derived to be from 30-jan-2016. (Table2_M doesn't have FEB2016 data)

I verified whether there was any version differences of Oracle in SIT and PROD and found it to be same from v$version (11.2.0.4.0).  Can you please explain this behavior as the same query on same view DDL in different environments returning different results with same data ...

Comment: When you say "as only one BIZ_DATE will be the output from the INNER query", are you referring to the `SELECT BIZ_DATE FROM TABLE2_M GROUP BY BIZ_DATE` subquery? Because if so, that subquery could (and probably will!) return multiple rows. "I hope that the inner query is sending out dates all 30-DEC-2015 to 30-JAN-2016" Why do you think that? The subquery is only going to return the dates passed in by those from TABLE1_D after it's filters have been applied (i.e. limited to between 1st Dec and 31st Dec.

Comment: On another note, please, please, PLEASE do **NOT** rely on implicit string-to-date conversion as you are doing here. Please use `to_date()` with a suitable format mask, eg. `WHERE BIZ_DATE BETWEEN to_date('01-DEC-2015', 'dd-MON-yyyy') AND to_date('31-DEC-2015', 'dd-MON-yyyy');` By not doing so, you are going to be in a world of pain if someone alters their nls_date_format setting when trying to run the prod query.

Comment: Please run `select * from nls_session_parameters` on both environments and compare their results. Please also append results of this query to the question. I bet that there are some differences in NLS setting.

Comment: Thank you Boneist and Kordirko;  The NLS settings are same and I will use to_date in further usage.  Yes the TABLE2_M did return multiple rows;  It is the issue with the data that I brought to SIT, when I inserted the same account numbers that are in 30-DEC-2015 by changing the biz_date to 30-JAN-2016, the select on the view for DEC2015 yielded 0 rows.

Comment: There are multiple joins involved.The users query looks like sel col1,...coln  from VW_TABLE1 T1, VW_TABLE3 T3, VW_TABLE4 T4 where t1.accnt_nbr=t2.accnt_nbr and t1.biz_date=t2.biz_date and t1.accnt_nbr=t3.accnt_nbr and t1.biz_date=t3.biz_date and T1.BIZ_DATE between TO_DATE('01-DEC-2015','DD-MON-YYYY') and TO_DATE('31-DEC-2015','DD-MON-YYYY')      d

Comment: due toBETWEEN, the query is running so long (each date in TABLE1_D has around 2,500,000 records) which was running for more than 3 days (2500 minutes and still running);  when the between is replaced with ='30-OCT-2015' it runs for 4 hrs Is there any way to tune it, because we cannot suggest them to use a varying hard-coded value for each reporting period as it makes their query to be variable for each reporting period( we cannot also suggest to use last_day of reporting period as for dec2015 it is 30dec2015) I understand that without explain plan it is hard to predict, but any suggestions...